# Error in longtable

Tags: longtable

```
\begin{longtable}{|lllll|}
\caption{Correlation analysis }
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}PO1: An ability to independently carry out research\\ development work to solve practical problems\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%

\end{longtable}
```

I am getting errors like misplaced \align, misplaced \omit when I compile this code.

Comment: You're missing a double-backslash directive immediately after `\caption{...}`. (Yeah, sometimes TeX and LaTeX error messages are truly cryptic.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That removed the errors the misplaced \align and misplaced